# Is there an efficient algorithm for clustering a big data array

Tags: python, bigdata

I have a csv and I want to read it with python. This csv has two columns, one is for the name of the customers and the other is for their age, I want to group the customers according to their age. However, in this csv there are 10^9 rows. So, I have to use an efficient algorithm for this job and not to read all the rows, is there a way to do this?

Comment: How do you think you can work on any data without reading it?

Comment: I want to read the data witch are going to give the best result

Comment: If your data doesn't fit your memory, you can have a look at [`dask` dataframes](http://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe.html).

Comment: Big data: stroring and processing a ton of really large CSV files.

Answer (score 0):

I presume you're asking how to cluster the data without reading all the rows *into memory* at once.

One idea is to use a two stage approach to clustering:

First, define your clusters with a sample (random subsets) of the data.  For example, you can randomly select 1,000 records (or some other reasonable value) and see how many clusters you need along with the cluster centers.  You can repeat this process several times until you are satisfied with your clusters.

Second, since now you have the cluster centers, you can "assign" each customer to their appropriate cluster (that is, using the nearest cluster center).  You can do this one-by-one for each record, or in convenient batches, since there is no need to do them all at once.  You can even do this assignment "lazily" (only when required) if you don't have to cluster all the records immediately.

This way you never have to load huge amounts of records into memory at once.